Remove Accept-Encoding Header in Flurl.Http
Flurl.Http sends in every Request the following Header:
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
This behaviour is since Update to Version 4.
I would contact API, which returns Error 406 when i send a request with this Header. How can i remove the Header in Flurl.Http to resolve this issue?
Here is my example request:
var request = $"https://{IP}"
  .AllowAnyHttpStatus()
  .AppendPathSegment(Endpoint)
  .WithHeader("Authorization", authHeader)
  .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

request.GetJsonAsync<JsonDocument>().Result;

before Update from Version 3 to Version 4, there was no Header "Accept-Encoding" sent.

A quick search led to that issue on Github.

Thanks to Etienne de Martel, he led me to the solution:
https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/748
Here is my sample Code:
FlurlHttp.Clients.WithDefaults(builder => builder.ConfigureInnerHandler(handler =>
{
  handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.None;
}));

FlurlHttp.ConfigureClientForUrl($"https://{IP}");

var request = $"https://{IP}"
  .AllowAnyHttpStatus()
  .AppendPathSegment(Endpoint)
  .WithHeader("Authorization", authHeader)
  .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

request.GetJsonAsync<JsonDocument>().Result;

